# Problems while sharing link to Vk and Facebook via Intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share, vk

I use this code to share a link to my app using android intent:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String lnk = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?referrer=utm_source=vk&utm_medium=share&utm_content=ASD23234343FFGGD&utm_campaign=ingame_share&id=com.my.super.app";
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, lnk);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Use this link to install my super app!");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
mainContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "What to choose?"));
```

**Question1**

When intent is received by installed app Vk on Vkontakte's wall I see my link with some scaring picture near it. 
It's not mine picture, no idea what it is at all! 
When I change package name to another, I see another strange picture with the same dimentions. What can I add to extra to get rid of this strange picture? Or at least give Vk link to my picture?

**Question2**

When intent is received by installed app Facebook on Facebook's wall I see my link without any other parameters except id:

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.super.app
```

I tried to Uri.encode the link, but it becomes broken. Changing parameters order doesn't help either. Is there way to share link on Facebook with referrer parameters?
The same thing if I use share link:

```
"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + Uri.encode(lnk) + "&t=" + Uri.encode(text)
```

But if I post link https://example.com/index.php? and add all the parameters, Facebook leave link as is. It looks like evil creature somehow hates Google Play and don't want to allow its refferal links :) 
Does anybody know how to manage this except redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Mistery discovered! google play page missing og:img metatag, so facebook chooses one image to show, vk - another (somebody's avatar in my case)
2. Facebook's crawler handle redirects and process GP links in special way. Maybe there's a way to share GP link with referral parameters, but I don't know. Rather create your own page, set correct Open Graph metas and put GP button on it.